# How do I install HDF5, openMPI .mod files with macports?

Tags: fortran, hdf5, macports, openmpi

I have installed HDF5 and openmpi-mp (also openmpi-devel-mp) on my Mac (Mojave 10.14.4, with latest Xcode and macports) with macports in order to compile a Fortran90 program that needs them. However, compilation fails with errors telling me that mpi.mod or hdf5.mod, which are requested by use statements, are not found. What else do I have to install or do in order to get all these modules? The path doesn't seem to be the issue, as I do see files like hdf5.h in /opt/local/include/, which I have specified as path.

Comment: The mod files should be in the same directory. Are they? How do you set the module include path?

Comment: No, there are no .mod files at all in that directory. I use the flag `-I/opt/local/include` with the compiler (mpif90). Indeed, there is no `hdf5.mod` anywhere in /opt/local.

Comment: Looks like something is weird with your installation, then. My hdf5 install directory has both .h and .mod files in path/include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For HDF5 *and* MPI, you need to have both libraries compiled with a single build environment (same compiler suite for C and Fortran). You need to build MPI first (possibly use the one from macports). Then, build HDF5 *referring to the OpenMPI install*.

The build from HDF5 will include the wrapped `h5pfc` (h5 for HDF5, p for parallel and fc for Fortran compiler). You should use `h5pfc -show` to see all the flags.

Comment: The question doesn't seem to suggest that parallel HDF5 is required.

Comment: The use of a `openmpi-*` wrapper, the mention of `mpi.mod`, and the openmpi tag led me to think it was. I'll wait for news from the poster to see whether I need to edit or remove my answer.

Comment: It is indeed intended for use with a parallel program. In order to avoid the problem with openMPI, I switched to mpich-mp for the time being (for some reason, that package does provide an mpi.mod) and reinstalled the HDF5 from macports, but there is still no .mod. Nor is there a `h5pfc` compiler, although `h5cc`and `h5c++` are there. Does anybody know of any Fortran add-ons? I couldn't find anything on Macports that looked like it.

Comment: If `h5pcc` is absent, it means that HDF5 was compiled without parallel support. The non-parallel Fortran wrapper is `h5fc`. The combinations are "with/without Fortran", "with/without MPI", and other variations (C++, Fortran 2003 interface, compression libs, etc). The solution is to build HDF5. Issue `export CC=mpicc` and `export FC=mpif90` (or the corresponding names on your system) before building HDF5.

Comment: Ok, with those flags it did produce the .mod files.